# Generic socket 940 CPU fan for HP XW9300 interchangeable with HP part number 411454-001

Tags: cooling, workstation, heatsink

I'm trying to find a generic Socket 940 CPU fan that will fit the air duct in an XW9300.

Note that two different CPU fan mounting schemes have been used on this machine.  One has two grommets in the motherboard that the CPU fan screws into and the other has a plastic collar and base plate.

The form factor I'm looking for is the former (see the picture below).  Two HP part numbers for fans in this form factor are 411454-001 (shown below) and 416055-001.  In a pinch one could buy the parts themselves off HP's web site (for a price), but I'm trying to find a generic equivalent.  I'm pretty sure I've seen a forum posting about this somewhere but I can't find it now.

Note that the dimensions are important as the machine has an air duct that fits over the fan.

- Can anyone tell me the manufacturer and model of an equivalent generic part?
- Better yet, do you know somewhere (preferrably in the UK) from which such an item can be obtained?

Update: I've found a very similar looking part on a U.S. parts web site, called ['Tyco 3U High Performance Athlon/Opteron cooler'](http://www.pcpartscollection.com/ty3uathipe3c.html).  The heatsink looks virtually identical, even down to the holes drilled into the top of the casing.  The main difference is the power connector on the fan.  The HP one has a 4 pin connector (IIRC the 4th wire is for a tachometer on the fan), so we might be getting close.  I still can't find the manufacturer's website, though - does this look familiar to anyone?

[image: Picture of 411454-001 CPU fan]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found HP's site for looking up parts, and located the [part you indicated](http://partsurfer.hp.com/Search.aspx?SearchText=416055-001). HP's parts site is pretty broken it seems, but I finally found [this page](http://h20141.www2.hp.com/hpparts/part_resellers.aspx?geo_code=EMEA) with a list of authorized part resellers in various countries. The UK is on that list. I would recommend calling one of those resellers and asking if they have either of the parts.

Comment: I'm trying to find a generic part.  One can buy HP parts through a convoluted process but they are very expensive for what they are.  I'm sure I saw a reference mentioned on a forum but I can't find it again.

Comment: What price range are you willing to take? Google product search turned up some stuff: http://bit.ly/bXKaiE

Answer (score 1):

See pcpartscollection.com   parts # is   411454-001  it's on sale in US for sale SHIPPED TO UK for53$ US.  THAT is CHEAP.  I bought TWO a while ago, and they DO FIT the duct.  I have same machine ;-).

Robert Two Bears
in Las Vegas

Answer (score 0):

Well, the only parts I can find are through [Google](http://www.google.co.uk/products?hl=en&client=firefox-a&q=XW9300+HP+fan&scoring=p), and all the parts seem to be from [Code Micro](http://www.codemicro.com/) and quite expensive for what they are, though that is one of the joys of buying branded equipment with the promise of manufacturer lock-in.  Seems that this is one of the niche areas where the far eastern copy-paste manufacturers couldn't be bothered to make you an alternative for.

All the other searches I can think to try suggest looking at HP or HP resellers.